# How do you deal with writing assemblers for objects that depend on each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, dto, data-transfer-objects

I have an `Animal` object, which has an `Owner`. An `Owner` object has an `Animal`. How do I write an assembler for an `Animal` and an assembler for an `Owner` that avoids cycles?

Please let me explain further:

I get an `Animal` `NSManagedObject` in Core Data and transform it into an `Animal` data transfer object (DTO), to be used throughout my application. I use an `Animal` assembler (aka mapper) for this.

Inside `Animal` assembler, I need to fill in the `Owner` property.  So, I need to assemble an `Owner` DTO. Well, inside the `Owner` DTO, I need to assemble an `Animal` DTO.  Hence the cycle.
To create a complete `Animal`, I need an `Owner` object.  To create an `Owner` object, I need an `Animal` object. Inside an `Animal` object, should I just store the reference to an `Owner`, like the `ownerId`?  In Core Data, it seems like objects being composed of each other are allowed.

I'd appreciate any strategies for solving this.

Comment: I don't think this is a memory management problem, @bbum, just "The car is locked. Where are the keys?" "They're in the car." "Well, never mind, unlock the door and we can get them out."

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, but ... Use a cache for the assembly (globally or per assembly, keyed by `objectID`). first hit the cache, if not exist assemble the missing object.